# Calling variables inside ViewHolder through Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

In my `RecyclerViewAdapter`, part of my codes are below:

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.music_item_lists, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       
        EqualizerView equalizerView, equalizerr;
        CardView image_card;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            
            equalizerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mini_eq_view);
            image_card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_card_view_play);
            equalizerView.stopBars();
            equalizerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Then in `MainActivity`, part of the codes are below

```
@Override
    public void playSongComplete() {
        Log.d("complete", "Playing song is complete: ");

    }
```

What I want to do is, if playing song is complete, I want to call

```
equalizerView.stopBars();
equalizerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

from inside method `playingSongComplete()`. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: do you have any list of data in your adapter which can be accessed by the viewholder?

Comment: `private ArrayList<ModelMusic> arrayList;` is accessed inside `ViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder`. And `private Activity activity;` accessed inside `onBindViewHolder`.

Answer (score 0):

create a function inside your adapter like

```
void stopEqualiser(){
   equalizerView.stopBars();
   equalizerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

then in the activity when music complete

```
@Override
public void playSongComplete() {
    
  // your recycler adapter
    adapter.stopEqualiser();

}
```

Comment: `equalizerView` isn't available in adapter itself, its a part of every item/`ViewHolder`

Comment: @snachmsm declare your `equalizerView ` outside of your `ViewHolder`

Comment: it can't be done, there are multiple `equalizerView`s. you clearly don't have idea how `RecyclerView` works...

Comment: as @snachmsm said, `equalizerView` is part of `ViewHolder`, And declaring `equalizerView ` outside `ViewHolder` is unable to do.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we cannot access variables inside viewholder from an activity. What we can do however is modify the data of the adapter and notify the adapter about the changed data. We can then handle the data change inside the `onBindViewHolder` method

you can create a boolean variable called `isSongComplete` with initial value false inside the adapter, then create function inside your adapter like this

```
void setComplete(){
    isSongComplete = true;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and in your `onBindViewHolder` method inside your viewholder class

```
@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (isSongComplete) {
        equalizerView.stopBars();
        equalizerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
    }
}
```

then in your `MainActivity`

```
@Override
public void playSongComplete() {
    Log.d("complete", "Playing song is complete: ");
    adapter.setComplete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dito cesartista. I have tried this but I got this errors "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.music.player.adapters.RecyclerViewAdapter.setComplete()' on a null object reference". Any solution for this error?

Comment: looks like `playSongComplete()` is called BEFORE `adapter` is initialized, thus [`NullPointerException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: just like @snachmsm said, if you want to modify something inside adapter or viewholder, you have to make sure that the adapter is not null before calling `playSongComplete()`. Maybe you can add more information on when `playSongComplete()` is called on your code and when the adapter is initialized.